Grafana cAdvisor Metrics
I have a kubernetes app running on minikube in Docker. I've installed Grafana, and can see certain logs in the UI, as well as confirmation that Alloy and cAdvisor are being scraped. However, I don't see the cAdvisor metrics being sent. When I tail the logs for the "grafana-k8s-monitoring-alloy-logs" pod, I see errors like this-
ts=2024-12-11T19:01:00.532390334Z level=error msg="error getting os stat" component_path=/ component_id=local.file_match.pod_logs path=/var/log/pods/default_grafana-k8s-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-ql4pm_39f6999f-4931-416a-bb76-42d373f354f6/node-exporter/0.log err="stat /var/log/pods/default_grafana-k8s-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-ql4pm_39f6999f-4931-416a-bb76-42d373f354f6/node-exporter/0.log: no such file or directory"
ts=2024-12-11T19:01:00.533017584Z level=error msg="error getting os stat" component_path=/ component_id=local.file_match.pod_logs path=/var/log/pods/default_worker-765456c688-28mhz_9a094181-01f8-4a73-a01c-ddd24fe0f107/worker/0.log err="stat /var/log/pods/default_worker-765456c688-28mhz_9a094181-01f8-4a73-a01c-ddd24fe0f107/worker/0.log: no such file or directory"

Here is my Helm file, can anyone advise on what needs updating here -
cluster:
  name: minikube
externalServices:
  prometheus:
    host: https://prometheus-prod-13-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net
    basicAuth:
      username: "195..
      password: glc_eyJ...
  loki:
    host: https://logs-prod-006.grafana.net
    basicAuth:
      username: "107...
      password: glc_eyJv...
  tempo:
    host: https://tempo-prod-24-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net:443
    basicAuth:
      username: "106...
      password: glc_ey...
metrics:
  enabled: true
  alloy:
    metricsTuning:
      useDefaultAllowList: true
    instances:
      - name: alloy-metrics
  cost:
    enabled: true
  kepler:
    enabled: true
  node-exporter:
    enabled: true
logs:
  enabled: true
  pod_logs:
    enabled: true
  cluster_events:
    enabled: true
traces:
  enabled: true
receivers:
  grpc:
    enabled: true
  http:
    enabled: true
  zipkin:
    enabled: true
  grafanaCloudMetrics:
    enabled: false
opencost:
  enabled: true
  opencost:
    exporter:
      defaultClusterId: minikube
    prometheus:
      external:
        url: https://prometheus-prod-13-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/api/prom
kube-state-metrics:
  enabled: true
prometheus-node-exporter:
  enabled: true
prometheus-operator-crds:
  enabled: true
kepler:
  enabled: true
alloy: {}
alloy-events: {}
alloy-logs: {}
alloy-metrics: 
  enabled: true
kubelet:
  enabled: true
cadvisor:
  enabled: true
node-exporter:
  enabled: true
    metricsTuning:
      useDefaultAllowList: true


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
